# How can I decode this instruction "call *fs:0x334" to know the exact function address?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64

During the runtime, how can I get the value in register fs and calculate the target function's address in "call *fs:0x334"? What kind of x86 assembly I can use?

Comment: Usually the selectors (like `fs`) have a value and the part behind is the offset from that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target function address in `call *fs:0x334` is the value stored at `fs:0x334`.

So, if you want to know what that address is, you can just load it.

e.g. `mov rax, [fs:0x334]` (nasm) or `mov %fs:0x334, %rax` (gas).

You don't need to know what `fs` itself points to (which is just as well: it points to an entry in a descriptor table, which you may or may not have privilege to read, which points to a linear address, which may or may not be accessible via any other segment selector).

On x86-64 Linux, the kernel and glibc co-operate to ensure that `fs` always points to a thread-local storage area for the currently running thread.  (On 32-bit x86 Linux, `gs` is used for this purpose instead.)